# How do i make the particular item selected in select box using jquery on document load

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

iam having the select box

```
<select id ="myselect">
<option value="AA">AA</option>
<option value="AB">AB</option>
<option value="AC">AC</option>
<option value="AD">AD</option>
</select>
```

so on document load I want to Make item "AC"  in the select box as the  default selected option on loading the document

`$('#myselect').children('option').text('AC').attr('selected', 'selected');`

so  with  this statement written it is  making my select box   to fill with values 'AC' completely for my select box. How do i correct that 
and  i tried in using the if statement comparing the value for 'AC'.And i dont have the "Value" for option as number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be do-able with:

```
$('option[value=AC]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Demo at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aguve4).

Comment: @david: Do we need to add select box id in front of this

Comment: No, not unless you really want to. It doesn't add anything, except a little specificity. But the `option[value=AC]` is already pretty specific. Unless you have multiple `options` with `value="AC"` you don't need to further specify.

Comment: This only works if you want to compare by value rather than by text. In his example they are the same, but his sample code was trying to check for .text() matching and in most cases this will be different from value.

Comment: @Sorpigal, true. But I thought I'd answer the question that was asked. And, usually, it's the `value` that's important in an xhtml form element, not the text used to *represent* that option's value.

Comment: is there a reason not to use .val() as in my answer?  Just curious because that's what i usually do.

Comment: Typically yes, however I have had cases where I want to say "The AC item" and not "database ID 4" or similar. It depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @fehays: He's not asking how to set or read values. He wants to set the selected attribute on a particular option element.

Comment: @fehays, I'm not sure to be honest. I chose my approach because it *felt* right to me at the time, both approaches seem to work though.

Comment: @Sorpigal: doesn't using .val() do just that when used on a select element?

Comment: @fehays, while the approaches are functionally equivalent, mine sets (as requested) the `selected` attribute, yours simply pre-selects the option. So, functionally equivalent, but there is a difference.

Comment: @David: I was thinking the same thing, but when I try either method, I don't see any difference in the DOM using firebug. But yes. I agree your approach is more accurate to the specific question asked. Now i'm just getting curious.

Comment: Using Chrome's web inspector shows the addition of the `selected` attribute in my version, but no DOM change for setting the `val()`. [edited] Oh, actually, no: you're right. There's no difference (which is really odd, since I could've *sworn* it showed up when first I checked the approach worked).

Comment: Yeah it is odd.  And if I try to select the currently selected option using 'option[selected="selected"]' that selector doesn't find it for either option.  strangeness... EDIT: check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/mtd6z/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value of the select.  This will select the option with the specified value.

```
$("#myselect").val('AC');
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtd6z/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
 $('#myselect').children('option').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'AC' }).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: You might be right.  After reading the part in the post that says "And i dont have the "Value" for option as number" I'm starting to wonder if what the poster meant was they need to compare the text value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using Javascript for this  (unless some very important reason ) -

It can be simply done this way

```
<select id ="myselect">
<option value="AA">AA</option>
<option value="AB">AB</option>
<option value="AC" selected="selected">AC</option>
<option value="AD">AD</option>
</select>
```